# Copy a part of a file to another using iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, filestream

I'm still practicing C++ and I have issues with char iterators over filestreams.

I want to copy a part of a file to another (temporary) file. I want to find a particular string in the first file (I used std::find algorithm), in order to know where I can "cut" the part of the file to be copied (hope that makes sense). My problem is that with the following code I have a compilation error that I don't really understand.

The part of my code in question looks like this:

```
ifstream readStream(fileName.c_str());
istreambuf_iterator<char> fStart(readStream);
istreambuf_iterator<char> fEnd;
auto position = find(fStart, fEnd, refToReplace); // refToReplace is a std::string
if (position != fEnd){ // If the reference appears in the file
    ofstream tempStream("temp.fsr"); // create the temp file
    copy(fStart, position , ostreambuf_iterator<char>(fluxTemp)); // and copy the part I want (before the matching string)
}
else{
            continue;
}
```

And the compilation error I'm getting in "stl_algo.h":

```
error: no match for 'operator==' in '__first.std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT, _Traits>::operator*<char, std::char_traits<char> >() == __val'
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Streams are not containers. They are _flows of data_...

Comment: It could be that you are passing position as an auto to copy() which expects an explicit type?

Comment: @KLibby I got the same error earlier, when I defined position with an explixit type. I tried to change it to auto in hope that was why I was getting an error, but it didn't change anything. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compilation error should come with an instantiation backtrace that tells you which call you made ultimately caused the error.

In your case, this will point at the `find` call. `find` looks for a single element, and the element type of your iterators is a single character, but you pass a string. (Based on your description. Your snippet doesn't actually tell us what the type of `refToReplace` is.)

The algorithm you're looking for is `search`, but that requires forward iterators, which streambuf iterators are not.

You will need to choose a different approach.

Comment: In build messages, I got a warning "required from here" at the line of my std::find call, I suppose it's what you are refering to.

Comment: I used the std::find algorithm because it works with the == operator so I thought it would work with strings, but what you said makes totally sense. ^^
But in the end, is there a way to search a substring in a file using iterators or must I change completely my code snippet?

Comment: There's no easy way. There are adapters that turn the stream iterators into forward iterators (Boost.Spirit includes one); it would work with those.

Comment: Well, okay. In the end, I copied the content of my first file into a string (using strinsgstream, idk if it's the best way but it works) instead of a temporary file, so I can use algorithms on that string. I wanted to avoid this method, because the content of my file is rather long, but it's not that bad and it works fine by me.
Thanks a lot for your help!